# Use of .Range variable causes an runtime error in vba

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

hope you can help me with a little issue. I want to copy a range of my current workbook to another open workbook.

Doesnt sound like an issue but it already crashes within the copy line.

I already tried to save the current/active Worksheet/book in a varaible and execute it like that but the error still appears. I used the combination of range and cells a ew times already so i doubt that this is the issue.

Maybe some of you had a similar problem already?
Or possible there is a better way of doing it?

Thanks alot in advance.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(AmountofRows, AmountofColumns)).Copy
```

Comment: What does `AmountofRows` and `AmountofColumns` equal?

Comment: 82 and 493 respectively. Which are the right values, so this part is working fine. They count the rows/columns a few lines above. No errors and the numbers a correct so this shouldnt be the issue. But thanks for the fast idea!

Comment: Instead of "Cells", use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Cells

Comment: In other words: add the specific and complete reference to the Cell you need, including which Workbook (in this case, ThisWorkbook) and which Worksheet (in this case, Worksheets("Test")

Comment: Now i get it okay, so the used "cells didnt really know what to reference but the . in front of it makes sure they use the before stated "path" so in this case "This workbook", Thanks :D got it now ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's due to you not being on the `Active` sheet when you run the command.

Try using this instead

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    .Range(.Cells(8, 2), .Cells(AmountofRows, AmountofColumns)).Copy
End With
```

The way you have used `Cells` will just use the active sheet which will then fail when you try to copy with a mixed declaration. Make sure you always define your ranges fully

Comment: Worked just fine, thank you alot!

just because of curiosity, shouldnt "thisworkbook" always refere to the one which th e code is written in? 
Well anyway it works, thanks ^^

Comment: Yes it does but it is the sheet reference that throws it out of place. You're defining the Range on one sheet and then using references to another sheet causing the issue with the copy